# Duvida SEO Open Graph

Tags: html5, seo, html-meta-tag

Como aplicar o Open Graph neste seguinte código:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="item-rede-social">
      <a rel="facebook" href="">
        <img src="imagens/facebook.png" class="img-responsive" alt="facebook"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="item-rede-social">
      <a rel="instagram" href="">
        <img src="imagens/instagram.png" class="img-responsive" alt="instagram"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="item-rede-social">
      <a rel="twitter" href="">
        <img src="imagens/twitter.png" class="img-responsive" alt="twitter"></a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Aplicar o Open Graph? O que seria isso?

Comment: http://marketingdeconteudo.com/meta-tags-para-redes-sociais/

Comment: Cara, [`Open Graph`](http://ogp.me/) até onde eu sei são `meta tags`. Dá uma olhada nesse link.

Comment: Sim, eu sei o que é o Open Graph, mas quero saber o que você quer dizer por aplicá-lo. Como o Wendel colocou, o Open Graph define metatags que especificam como o Facebook irá interagir com sua página. Qual seria a relação com os links de mídias sociais apresentados na pergunta?